# How to remove menubar in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

i know that i can create menu bar with `add_cascade`
like this code:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import * 
from time import strftime
  
# creating tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title('Menu Demonstration')
  
# Creating Menubar
menubar = Menu(root)
  
# Adding File Menu and commands
file = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='File', menu = file)
file.add_command(label ='New File', command = None)
file.add_command(label ='Open...', command = None)
file.add_command(label ='Save', command = None)
file.add_separator()
file.add_command(label ='Exit', command = root.destroy)
  
# Adding Edit Menu and commands
edit = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Edit', menu = edit)
edit.add_command(label ='Cut', command = None)
edit.add_command(label ='Copy', command = None)
edit.add_command(label ='Paste', command = None)
edit.add_command(label ='Select All', command = None)
edit.add_separator()
edit.add_command(label ='Find...', command = None)
edit.add_command(label ='Find again', command = None)
  
# Adding Help Menu
help_ = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Help', menu = help_)
help_.add_command(label ='Tk Help', command = None)
help_.add_command(label ='Demo', command = None)
help_.add_separator()
help_.add_command(label ='About Tk', command = None)
  
# display Menu
root.config(menu = menubar)
mainloop()
```

But how can i remove them?

Comment: It is not clear what you want is to *delete the whole menubar* (as said in the title) or *delete item inside a menubar*.

Comment: Look at this answer [Tkinter menu delete item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906815/tkinter-menu-delete-item)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `delete` to delete a menubar

```
menubar.delete ( 'name' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556387/hide-or-removing-a-menubar-of-tkinter-in-python)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38557588/20585541).
Here's some example code from the answer linked to:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

submenu = Menu(menubar)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Submenu", menu=submenu)
submenu.add_command(label="Option 1")
submenu.add_command(label="Option 2")
submenu.add_command(label="Option 3")

def remove_func():
    emptyMenu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=emptyMenu)

remove_button = Button(root, text="Remove", command=remove_func)
remove_button.pack()
```

Basically, this code has a function called `remove_func()`, which creates an empty menu (called `emptyMenu`) and sets *that empty menu* to be the menubar.

Answer (score 0):

To have an empty menubar, you don't have to add any cascades or buttons.
Samples from your code with the implementation:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import * 
from time import strftime
  
# creating tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title('Menu Demonstration')
  
# Creating Menubar
menubar = Menu(root)
  
# Adding File Menu and commands
file = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add function.

```
def remove_menubar():
    menubar.delete(0, END)

remove_button = Button(root, text="Remove", command=remove_menubar)
remove_button.pack()

root.config(menu = menubar)
mainloop()
```